# Post to friends wall using FBWebdialogs

Tags: ios, facebook

I used below code to post on **Facebook**,entered all required details in Params dictionary and added in **FBWebDialogs**, but the post is not displaying in friend wall.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                        @"name" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"name"]],
                        @"caption" : @"",
                        @"description" :[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"desc_title"],
                        @"picture" : str_link,
                        @"link" : @"",
                      };

[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                parameters:params
                                                   handler:
    ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error)
     {
       //NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
       [self.indicator stopAnimating];
     }
     else 
     {
        if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) 
        {
          //NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
        } 
        else 
        {
          //NSLog(@"Story published.");
        }
    }}];
   }
 }];
```

Expecting ideas to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alertView show];
     }
     else if(session.isOpen)
     {
         //NSLog(@"%@",Data_Dict);

         NSString *str_link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@uploads/%@-5.jpg",app.Main_url,[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"deal_id"]];
         //NSLog(@"%@",str_link);

         NSDictionary *params = @{
                                  @"name" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"name"]],
                                  @"caption" : @"",
                                  @"description" :[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"desc_title"],
                                  @"picture" : str_link,
                                  @"link" : @"",
                                  };

         // Invoke the dialog
         [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                parameters:params
                                                   handler:
          ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
              if (error) {
                  //NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
                  [self.indicator stopAnimating];
              } else {
                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                      //NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                      [self.indicator stopAnimating];
                  } else {
                      //NSLog(@"Story published.");
                      [self.indicator stopAnimating];
                  }
              }}];
     }

 }];
[self.indicator stopAnimating];

return;
```

Comment: thanks for ur reppy. where i need to use this code, [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:?

Comment: Its new concept to use fb sharing ,So, pls help to get my requirement.

Comment: first you create appid ?.

Comment: ok, then wat things i need to do

Comment: appId and facebook.framework

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48328/discussion-between-ramdy-and-bhavesh-nai)

Comment: I've doubt in your code. pls make me clear

Comment: I used code same like u post. but still i'm not getting result. The post not displaying in friend's wall. y?

Comment: replace     NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"name" : str_name,
                             @"caption" : @"",
                             @"description" : @"",
                             @"picture" : @"",
                             @"link" : str_link,
                             @"to":str_id,
                             };

Comment: No, i'm not getting any error.

Comment: app.Main_url,[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"deal_id]. what values these parameters having?

Comment: app.main_url = @"www.yourproject.com";//must 
[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"deal_id] = @"something discription";

Comment: Pls check my code, NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TESTING PURPOSE", @"name",@"473699602729483",@"app_id",user.id,@"to",@"http://www.google.com",@"link", nil]; app_id is fb app id, and user.id is selected friend's id.

Comment: NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"name" : @"TESTING PURPOSE",
                             @"caption" : @"",
                             @"description" : @"",
                             @"picture" : @"",
                             @"link" : @"www.google.com",
                             @"to":@"YourUserID",
                             };
//Try this

Comment: i thing no need for app id here.

Comment: app id use in info.plist