# post on friends wall in Facebook using FBWebDialogs in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004917/post-to-friends-wall-using-fbwebdialogs) to post on friends wall but its not posting actually instead it just lists the no of friends and allows for multiple selection of friends, there is no option for posting on friends wall.

Not getting satisfactory answer please help me how to post on friends wall using FBWebDialogs, as other ways using Graph api to post on users wall is disabled by facebook.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer of my own question, how easier it was !! but it took my couple of days reaching out there.

To post on your friends wall first of all you need is a permission **publish_actions**.

And here is the simple code :

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[params setObject:@"YOUR DESC" forKey:@"description"];
[params setObject:@"YOUR LINK" forKey:@"link"];
[params setObject:@"YOUR CAPTION" forKey:@"caption"];
[params setObject:@"FRIEND_ID" forKey:@"to"];

[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@" RESULT : %u",result);
                                          }
 ];
```

Make sure you have added Facebook SDK in you bundle
and have imported necessary class.
That's it..

Answer (score 0):

Look on this,

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"name" :@"Your name",
                                      @"caption" : @"",
                                      @"description" :@"Your description"],
                                      @"picture" : @"Your Image link",
                                      @"link" : @"Your link",
                                      };

         // Invoke the dialog
         [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                parameters:params
                                                   handler:
          ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
              if (error) {
                  NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
              } else {
                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                      NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"Story published.");
                  }
              }}];
```